# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception

```
Warning 1   D:\MyPath\SomeAscx.cs: ASP.NET runtime error: 


            Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, 
            Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a'
            or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition 
            does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have removed the reference and am not using it in code why would this still be an issue. I have tried cleaning solution, rebuilding, open and closing solution but still no success. Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even if you removed direct references, something else might still require that dll.

I'd suggest:

1. Recycle your IIS application pool (or run IISRESET from the command prompt to reset the entire web server)
2. turn on [FusLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and check who is the real "offender"

Comment: Sweet the offender was another project sigh :'( haha Fixed now and Thanks for the excellent FusLog tip!

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if **your project name conflicts with a nuget package you referenced**. I wasted about 30 minutes before I realized what is going on.

I was doing a ReactJS tutorial, so I created a project called *React*, and then later I imported ReactJS.NET from nuget.

When I hit build, Visual Studio will build `React.dll` in bin folder since my project name is *React*, this dll overwrites the `React.dll` imported by nuget package ReactJS.NET

So my project blew up... and I wasted 30 minutes scratching my head.