# Could not load file or assembly error - looking for wrong computer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

So I had this (probably not) great idea of saving a asp.net mvc project on OneDrive so I could work on it on both a desktop and laptop system. This actually has worked well for several weeks, but today when I tried to open it I get Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've been searching Stackoverflow for a fix to this, but so far nothing I've tried has worked.

Is there a way I can just delete or edit the problem assembly?

EDIT:

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution, no luck.
I am using Git with this project. I've tried restoring from a recent commit, but I get the same error.
The stack trace mentions System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, but I don't see this file in references.

EDIT:

Thanks for the continued suggestions, all. I did manage to get fuslogvw working, and it let me to my root folder, where using my laptop to edit the solution had somehow generated a file called *projectname-laptopname* (those are generics of course.) So I deleted this file, cleaned and rebuilt, however I am still getting the same error when I try to run the solution.

Comment: You should use a Source Version Control System.

Comment: If you need a free Version Control System, Visual Studio Online (VisualStudio.com) is free and you can use TFS or GIT.

Comment: I've got a recent commit on GitHub, but I tried reverting to that and got the same error.

Comment: you should edit the csproj file in a text editor and remove the problem file.

Comment: @GlennFerrie - I tried this and searched the file, but I can't find any reference to the problem file.  Good suggestion though, I had high hopes for it.

Comment: Do the tips here help you any?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129802/exception-from-hresult-0x80131040

Comment: @JohnieKarr no, though the fuslogvw sounds promising. Unfortunately, that isn't working on my PC either (no output) which I guess is a common problem. One more thing to troubleshoot.

Comment: do you have any libraries downloaded using NuGet? and the "packages" folder that contain them is missing or something?

Comment: Thanks for the continued suggestions, all. I did manage to get fuslogvw working, and it let me to my root folder, where using my laptop to edit the solution had somehow generated a file called projectname-laptopname (those are generics of course.) So I deleted this file, cleaned and rebuilt, however I am still getting the same error when I try to run the solution.

Comment: @GlennFerrie - It seems you are on the right track with your idea, however I removed the file from the solution folder, and I still get the same error. Any suggestions there?

Comment: have you gone through the [official troubleshooting guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5017.troubleshooting-the-located-assembly-s-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference.aspx) for this error?

Comment: Check the 'target framework' versions of the project(s) from both the desktop and laptop. See if they match. Sometimes having a lib requiring full framework, but the project being on Client Profile framework can lead to failures.

Answer (score 1):

How I ended up fixing this was to comb through the error line by line, which led me to the bin directory (if anyone doesn't know bin is a hidden file, but the 'show all files' icon reveals it in solution explorer.)

From there I went through each dll, until I found one with the name of myproject-mylaptop.dll. There were actually more than one of these .dll files.

I don't know how or why this file was generated, or why it took so long to become a problem, but deleting all of them and then rebuilding the project solved the issue.

Thanks to everyone for your help! It kept me looking and gave me ideas of new ways to search for the problem. This was the thorniest issue I've had with VS to date.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your references in Solution Explorer and look for the one that has a warning icon on it.  This would be the reference that is broken.

To band-aid this you can delete the reference from there and re-add it.

The hard way would be to modify the path to the reference directly in your project file.  If you really want to go this route, this [blog post](https://johniekarr.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/configuration-specific-reference-location/) might get you started, though keep in mind it's solving a different problem.

If you are going to be doing work on multiple machines, you'll want to keep your third-party references in a folder in your solution and check your work into a source control system, like TFS, SVN, Git, Mecurial, etc..., that will get checked in with your work.  That way when you change computers you don't lose the reference.

Visual Studio Online ([VisualStudio.com](http://VisualStudio.com)) will allow you to use TFS or GIT, and it's free and integrates with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I expanded references and did not see any warning icons.